# Efficeint Handling of Multipart SMS or Long SMS in Android

Tags: android, sms, multipart

I have a few questions on Android `SMSManager`.

1. How do I send long SMS, say  more than 160 characters. My application send SMS
     as an email when there if no wifi/data connection. The SMS as email 
     is retrieved by the server and the server sent a msg: "Your email has been 
     recieved". How do I show this message on the alert dialog box.
2. How do I retrieve long SMS?
3. Four of my activity  is supposed to send sms, so do i need to have multiple BroadcastReciecver for each activity or can i simple handle with one BroadcastReciever? Can i have a snippet code on such?

Currently i part of code handles as all above. But i know my codes are in-efficeint. Thats one reason i have such question.
Please bear my question.